# Azure Mobile App redirecting Http POST calls to GET when Azure Active Directory Authentication is enabled

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I'm going through the .NET portions of the Azure Mobile App backend tutorials found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk

I got everything setup nicely with the default example `TodoItemController`. I added push notifications as [instructed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started-push) by adding code to the `PostToDoItem` controller method.

I then tested the POST call using Postman and putting in a simple new item:[image]

Upon which I get a successful push notification in my Xamarin.Forms mobile app:

[image]

However, when I enable Azure Active Directory authentication in my Mobile App Service while leaving "Allow Anonymous requests (no action)" on, I'm no longer able to send a POST call with Postman. More specifically, it looks like the App Service receives the POST request, but immediately redirects it and yields a GET request instead. This causes the GetAllToDoItems method in the controller to be called instead of the PostToDoItem method. I see this in the log stream:

```
 > 2017-05-31T01:33:46  PID[4292] Verbose     Received request: POST
> http://XYZ.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0
> 2017-05-31T01:33:46  PID[4292] Information Redirecting:
> https://XYZ.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0
> 2017-05-31T01:33:46  PID[4292] Verbose     Received request: GET
> https://XYZ.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0
> 2017-05-31T01:33:46  PID[4292] Verbose     [Routes(Preview)] No
> authorization configuration was found. 2017-05-31T01:33:46  PID[4292]
> Information Request, Method=GET,
> Url=https://XYZ.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0,
> Message='https://XYZ.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0'
> 2017-05-31T01:33:46  PID[4292] Information Message='TodoItem',
> Operation=DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController
> 2017-05-31T01:33:46  PID[4292] Information
> Message='XYZService.Controllers.TodoItemController',
> Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create 2017-05-31T01:33:46 
> PID[4292] Information
> Message='XYZService.Controllers.TodoItemController',
> Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController
> 2017-05-31T01:33:46  PID[4292] Information Message='Selected action
> 'GetAllTodoItems()'',
> Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction
```

I would've expected this POST call to work the same as when I have App Service authentication set to OFF since I told Azure to take no action when anonymous requests come in. Am I misunderstanding something here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After we enable the authentication/authorization for the app service, if we send the request using the **HTTP** protocol, the server will redirect it to **HTTPS** via 302 response.

To make it work in this scenario, you can send the request using the **HTTPS** protocol instead of **HTTP**. This should work if you enable the **Allow Anonymous requests(no action)** feature.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was looking at this for so long that I didn't even notice I was using HTTP instead of HTTPS while I was going through the steps!